# How to stop hibernate annotation to modify table structure automaticall?

Tags: hibernate, annotations

In my database(mysql),there is a table called  like this:

```
Project table'structure 
----------------------------------------------------------------
Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| create_time | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

And I have a entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project{
     Long  id;
     Date  createTime;
}
```

Each time to start server,the column "create_time" will be altered to "createTime" automatically,and all data will be cleared,this is very dangerous.Maybe I can modify database's user permisson to stop hibernate to do this action.The question is how to stop this dangerous action in hibernate level?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(name="create_time")
Date createTime;
```

The other possibility is to turn off the schema update in hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: Thanks.I am new to annotation,the questio is can I use annotation to replace xml entirelly,if yes,how to disable schema update by annotation.

Comment: You still need the hibernate.cfg.xml file... you'll disable the schema update by omitting the hbm2ddl.auto property from the file.